# Find out if jar.exe is available

Tags: java, jar

I want to execute "jar.exe" from my code using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar.exe -xf " + completePathToJar);
```

but I only want to call it if the jar.exe really exists (the jdk is installed).
How can I make sure the jar.exe really exists on the machine?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If jar.exe doesn't exist than how you would be able to run your main java program from where you are trying to check java.exe location ?

Comment: To run a java program, you don't need the jar.exe. The jar.exe is not included in a JRE while it is in a JDK.

Comment: To check if you have `jdk` you can search for certain environment variables like `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`. If you are not able to find it, you can ask the user to specify the `jdk` installation path.

Comment: @tabina , sorry I thought you was looking for java.exe, Just realize your question was for jar.exe and not for java.exe

Comment: I would probably rather use `ZipOutputStream` or some pure Java decompressor rather than calling an external application.

Comment: Failing that, you can try checking the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to find out the directory of your Java installation. It isn't a 100% method but it's better than blindly going through all directories..

Comment: @biziclops Thank you, I will try the ZipOutputStream.

Comment: Or the built-in jar API. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html

Comment: Using util.jar.JarFile is the solution I was looking for. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

To check weather the file exists or not use File class

```
    File exeFile = new File(validExeFilePath);
    if(exeFile.exists()){
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar.exe -xf " + completePathToJar);
    }
```

Comment: So what do you put into validExeFilePath? How do you know the path of your jar.exe?

Comment: @tabina "your jar.exe" doesn't really exist, there can easily be numerous available on the system. Say: a 32 bits and a 64 bits JDK, perhaps you still have a legacy JDK installed for older projects, etc.

Comment: @Gimby But how would you check if any jar.exe exists?

Comment: Would the exec-call to the jar.exe give me any return value I could check to see if the execution failed?